# Selecting Datasource of Rich Text components

Tags: sxa

We have an SXA site that we have started to build out.  As we have gone through the process we realized that we needed to change how we are doing the page designs, and had to create new ones.

When changing page designs all of the rich text content is removed.  Fine.

The problem is when I go to add it back in, and drag/drop a Rich Text component onto the page, Sitecore automatically creates a new blank Text item, and I have to change the associated content and then delete the newly created one.

Is there any way to be able to select the data source of a Rich Text item before  the new one gets created?  It would save me a decent amount of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Reusable Rich Text** instead of **Rich Text**

They are the same renderings with one exception.

**Reusable Rich Text** asks about data source while normal **Rich Text** just creates it automatically.

Comment: Does that also place the Text item in the Data folder instead of making it an asset of the page?

Comment: You can pick whether it should go in the local data folder for the page or the sites data folder IIRC